# Ошибка при обновлении json-файла

Tags: python, json

Допустим, что есть список переменных:

```
value_list = [ alpha, delta, omega ]
```

и список переменных со значениями из файла `cache.json`:

```
cache_value_list = [ alphaCache, deltaCache, omegaCache ]
```

А также сам список ключей из файла `cache.json`:

```
cache_key_list = [ 'alpha_key', 'delta_key', 'omega_key']
```

Наша задача состоит в том, чтобы сравнить первый список со вторым и перезаписать `cache.json`, в случаи, если значения из первого спикска не равны значениям `cache.json` из второго списка:

```
for val, cache_val, cache_key in zip(value_list, cache_value_list, cache_key_list):
    if val != cache_val:
        updateJson(CACHE_FILE_PATH, val, cache_key)
```

`updateJson` выглядит вот так:

```
def updateJson(path, v, k):
    jsonFile = open(path, 'r')
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()

    tmp = data[k]
    data[k] = v

    jsonFile = open(path, "w+")
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    jsonFile.close()
```

Проблема в том, что мне выдаёт ошибку:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Как я понял, проблема в этой части кода:

```
    tmp = data[k]
    data[k] = v
```

ибо нельзя использовать списки, т.е `cache_key_list`.

Но как тогда быть? Что я делаю не так и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте `tuple(v)`

Comment: Зачем портить свой вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/223536).